# How do I map this function over pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I might be approaching this completely wrong, but I currently have a function as shown below that gets the link of the first youtube video that I that comes up on the search results, given a string input:

```
def searchYTLink(title):
    query = urllib.parse.quote(title)
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    result =  soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'yt-uix-tile-link'})[0]
    return 'https://www.youtube.com' + result['href']
```

Now I want to input a list of strings to this function and map it over all my worker nodes. To achieve this, I wrote the code below:

```
# Make sure that you initialize the Sppark Context
sc = SparkContext(appName="MusicClassifier")
searchTest = ['videoa', 'videob', ...]
sc.parallelize(searchTest).map(searchYTLink)
```

Is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One tiny thing to fix - you need an action

Your example looks fine, up to a point. In order to actually execute any code you'll need to add an [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) to the end of your chain of `RDD` methods. The most straightforward action is typically [`collect`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.collect), which will just gather the final value of each partition and return it as a single `RDD`:

```
sc.parallelize(searchTest).map(searchYTLink).collect()
```

## Notes

- You do indeed appear to be using `map` correctly. The function you pass into it should take exactly one argument, which `searchYTLink` does.
- For performance reasons, you may also want to look into [`mapPartitions(func)`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions). `mapPartitions` is exactly like `map`, but in this case `func` should be a function that takes a whole chunk of values at a time.

Comment: If I am collecting this data, wouldn't it be best if I just proceeded to use a dataframe instead (asking for your opinion)? But the rest of the answer seems to clarify a lot of things for me.

Comment: I personally am not a fan of dataframes (they're slow (which is at cross-purposes with Pyspark itself) and never seem to do quite what you want) and prefer working with raw `RDD`s. I seem to be in the minority though, so you should go with what you think will fit your problem best.